# UrlHelper.RouteUrl( routeName, RouteValueDictionary ) returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application running on .NET 4.6.1.

I have an Area in my application called "Foo" and in my Area registration I add a named route like so:

```
RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {

    context.MapRoute("Foo_Bar", "{tenantName}/foo/{fooId}/{fooRevision}", new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index" } );

}
```

From my Razor view code I want to generate a link using this route, so I do:

```
RouteValueDictionary rd = new RouteValueDictionary( this.Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values );
rd["fooId"      ] = "123";
rd["fooRevision"] = "4";

this.Url.RouteUrl("Foo_Bar", rd );
```

However this returns null. No exception. No other side-effects.

The debugger shows that `rd` contains 5 named values: `tenantName`, `controller`, `action`, `fooId`, and `fooRevision`. I also added `area` during Debugging just to make sure, however it still returns null.

I verified that the route exists because `this.Url.RouteCollection["Foo_Bar"]` returns the `System.Web.Routing.Route` object corresponding to that route.

I tried .NET Source Stepping and I was able to step 1 level into `UrlHelper`, but stepping into the `GenerateUrl` function fails and Visual Studio 2015 U2 always steps over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to step-into the .NET Framework source code to figure this one out - first into `System.Web.Mvc.dll` to get into `UrlHelper.RouteUrl` which then called into `System.Web.Routing.dll` (which is now a stub for `System.Web.dll` in .NET 4.5).

The answer lies in `ParsedRoute::Bind` ( http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Routing/ParsedRoute.cs )

So the problem was in this line:

```
RouteValueDictionary rd = new RouteValueDictionary( this.Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values );
```

This causes `rd` to copy (inherit) the values from the current request-context, I thought this was desirable. I thought that because the route `Foo_Bar` provides a default `controller` and `action` parameter values, that it would always use those in preference to whatever was in `rd`, but I was wrong.

The `rd` passed into `UrlHelper.RouteUrl` contained values for `controller`, and `action` but they were for the current request, and so were different than the defaults.

The definition of `ParsedRoute::Bind` is such that it aborts if a provided `RouteValueDictionary` provides a parameter value different to the defaults (see lines 133 through 149 in `ParsedRoute.cs`.

I feel the framework should throw an exception in that case, rather than returning null - because this behavior doesn't seem to be well documented - especially as all of the search results say the problem is simply that the route doesn't exist or insufficient parameters were passed - in my case, the problem was that in a way *too many* parameters were being passed.

Answer (score 0):

A `null` value indicates the requested values did not match any route. Since you are also specifying a route name explicitly (which acts like a filter over the route table), it is safe to say that the route `Foo_Bar` does not match the route value input that was provided.

You have not provided a default value for `{tenantName}` (which is fine if there is no sensible default), so `{tenantName}` is a required value. When you provide a value for `{tenantName}`, the URL is generated correctly.

```
RouteValueDictionary rd1 = new RouteValueDictionary();
rd1["fooId"] = "123";
rd1["fooRevision"] = "4";

var url1 = this.Url.RouteUrl("Foo_Bar", rd1);
// url1 value is null

RouteValueDictionary rd2 = new RouteValueDictionary();
rd2["fooId"] = "123";
rd2["fooRevision"] = "4";
rd2["tenantName"] = "SomeTenant";

var url2 = this.Url.RouteUrl("Foo_Bar", rd2);
// url2 value is /SomeTenant/foo/123/4
```

> **NOTE:** MVC [automatically reuses route values from the current request](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346) that are not provided explicitly. There is no need to explicitly add `this.Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values` to the route collection.

Of course, this means you might not have to explicitly add `tenantName` to the route collection, depending whether the the context that you run this code in already has it.

Comment: Even when I provide an explicit `tenantName` in the dictionary, it still returns null. This is weird.